# Importing External Packages for PythonOperator Tasks

Tags: module, airflow, pyodbc

I am trying to import the pyodbc package into my Airflow Task so I can create a connection object to a SQL database - however Airflow says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'".

I am running Airflow 2.1.2 within a Docker Container and I tried opening an interactive terminal and running: 'pip install pyodbc', but I get an error from the container: 'ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc'.

What is the best practice for installing packages into Airflow so that tasks can reference them?

Thanks

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Which database do you want to access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own custom image.

We have the whole set of [documentation about it](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html)

In most cases, when you want to just add a PyPI package, simple ["extending" the image](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#adding-a-new-pypi-package) will work.

But in your case you need to add some apt-dependencies and "customize" the image rather than extend it, because `pyodbc` apparently requires "build-essentials" (compilers) and some [additional "apt" dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449971/pip-install-pyodbc-failed-error-failed-building-wheel-for-pyodbc).

This is a bit more complex than extending the image and requires using whole airflow sources (for now - it will be a bit [nicer in the future](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11740)). However what you will get as the result will be highly-optimized for size, production-ready image customized in the way you need it - pretty much the same image Airflow Community builds and test but with "odbc" installed additionally.

See [comparision](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#extending-vs-customizing-the-image) of "extending" vs. customizing. Also [my talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDr3Y7q2XoI) from Airflow Summit 2020 might be helpful to understand the two approaches.

There are quite a few examples to follow in the documentation.

Just to explain your particular case. For odbc you need to get:

- `unixodbc-dev` as additional dev apt deps (to compile the odbc package)
- `odbc` as additional airflow extra (see explanation below)
- `unixodbc` as additional runtime apt deps (to have runtime version of the odbc libraries)

Regarding extras - Airflow has a set of extras that can be installed together with main airflow package [extras reference here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/extra-packages-ref.html) - it will bring the "golden" versions (those tested by the Airflow CI system) set of dependencies needed as well as the [odbc provider package](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-odbc/stable/index.html) released at the time of 2.1.2 release.
The provider package has all the operators/sensors/hooks for ODBC that you might find helpful in building your DAGs.

I just tested this command (you need to get latest airflow sources for that) and it worked for me:

```
docker build . \
   ​--build-arg PYTHON_BASE_IMAGE="python:3.6-slim-buster" \
   ​--build-arg AIRFLOW_VERSION="2.1.2" \
   --build-arg ADDITIONAL_AIRFLOW_EXTRAS="odbc" \
   ​--build-arg ADDITIONAL_DEV_APT_DEPS="unixodbc-dev" \
   ​--build-arg ADDITIONAL_RUNTIME_APT_DEPS="unixodbc" \
   ​--tag "myodbc-airflow:2.1.2"
```

Then you can use the `myodbc-airflow:2.1.2` instead of `apache/airflow:2.1.2` in docker-compose/k8s or whatever deployment you use.

Same approach can be taken for any other dependency that requires compilation and some additional "apt" dependencies - you can specify multiple extras and multiple dependencies and even new python dependencies not foreseen by Airflow extras this way.