# Installing pyodbc during Openshift Build/Deployment

Tags: python, kubernetes, odbc, openshift, pyodbc

I am getting an error when installing pyodbc as a part of my Openshift deployment.  There are numerous threads explaining the solution, including this one:  [pip install pyodbc failed ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449971/pip-install-pyodbc-failed-error-failed-building-wheel-for-pyodbc)

Error:

```
Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'pyodbc' extension
      In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
      src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
       #include <sql.h>
                       ^
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
```

**My question is:** how do I kick off an apt install (or sudo) as a part of my deployment?
I am using the OpenShift GUI.

I'm using requirements.txt to force the PIP install of all the dependencies:

```
pandas
numpy
dash
dash_core_components
dash_html_components
plotly.express
dash
plotly
sqlalchemy
matplotlib
pyodbc
powershift-image
```

YAML contents for the build:

```
kind: BuildConfig
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.openshift.io/vcs-ref: master
    app.openshift.io/vcs-uri: >-
      ssh://git@sourcecode.xxdeletedxx_reports.git
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/ci-testline-analysis-adp/buildconfigs/adp-testline-reports-git
  resourceVersion: '319828205'
  name: adp-testline-reports-git
  uid: 6d2f69e9-8d8d-4c72-bdc0-5838be4649d9
  creationTimestamp: '2022-02-08T18:30:16Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
      time: '2022-02-08T20:25:20Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:app.openshift.io/vcs-ref': {}
            'f:app.openshift.io/vcs-uri': {}
            'f:openshift.io/generated-by': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/component': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/part-of': {}
            'f:app.openshift.io/runtime': {}
            'f:app.openshift.io/runtime-version': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:output':
            'f:to':
              .: {}
              'f:kind': {}
              'f:name': {}
          'f:runPolicy': {}
          'f:source':
            'f:contextDir': {}
            'f:git':
              .: {}
              'f:ref': {}
              'f:uri': {}
            'f:sourceSecret':
              .: {}
              'f:name': {}
            'f:type': {}
          'f:strategy':
            'f:sourceStrategy':
              .: {}
              'f:env': {}
              'f:from':
                .: {}
                'f:kind': {}
                'f:name': {}
                'f:namespace': {}
            'f:type': {}
    - manager: openshift-apiserver
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
      time: '2022-02-10T14:04:32Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:triggers': {}
        'f:status':
          'f:lastVersion': {}
  namespace: ci-testline-analysis-adp
  labels:
    app: adp-testline-reports-git
    app.kubernetes.io/component: adp-testline-reports-git
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: adp-testline-reports-git
    app.kubernetes.io/name: python
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: TestLine-Report
    app.openshift.io/runtime: python
    app.openshift.io/runtime-version: 3.8-ubi7
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'adp-testline-reports-git:latest'
  resources: {}
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: openshift
        name: 'python:3.8-ubi7'
      env:
        - name: APP_FILE
          value: main.py
  postCommit: {}
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: >-
        ssh://git@sourcecode.xxdeletedxx_reports.git
      ref: master
    contextDir: /
    sourceSecret:
      name: openshift-key-socialcoding
  triggers:
    - type: Generic
      generic:
        secretReference:
          name: adp-testline-reports-git-generic-webhook-secret
    - type: ImageChange
      imageChange:
        lastTriggeredImageID: >-
          image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/python@sha256:c5d24000000000000000000000
    - type: ConfigChange
  runPolicy: Serial
status:
  lastVersion: 15
```

Comment: Can you list the yaml/repo/chart/dockerfile or whatever you use to deploy pyodbc?

Comment: I added the requirements.txt file contents

Comment: Sorry I missed to say that, but you probably also want to add the actual error.

Comment: Updated the question to include the error text

Comment: Anyone........ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my issue, I had to create custom Dockerfile and deploy the application in OpenShift as a Docker image.  Specifically, I used add --> from Dockerfile instead of add--> Import from Git (Python builder image) in the GUI.
The Import from Git method does not allow enough flexibility to install all of the needed packages. (pyodbc , etc.)